# Remove lines from Text file c#

Tags: c#

I have a text file from which I would like to remove an entire line of text. I want to delete the entire line of text if the first amount of characters in that line exceed a certain amount before the white space starts in that line, I hope that makes sense.

Example:

```
1234567890************** (* = white space such as SPACE or TAB)

1234567890123********** (* = white space such as SPACE or TAB)
```

The amount of characters before white space in Example line 2 exceed 10 characters so the entire line of text should be deleted.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: share some code whcih you have tried

Answer (score 0):

first read the text in, line by line.
for each line check the first 10th chars. If they are not an "invalid char" (tab or space) include the line in the final string. Then store the final string. (you can overwrite the original file if needed)

```
List<char> invalidChars = new List<char> {" ", ";"};
string finalString = "";
using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader("TestFile.txt"))
        {
            //grab line
            String line = sr.ReadToEnd();
            //grab first 10 chars of the line
            string firstChars = line.substring(0,10);
            //check if contains 
            bool hasInvalidChars = false;
            foreach(char c in invalidChars)
            {
                if(firstChars.toLowerInvariant().IndexOf(c) == 1)
                   hasInvalidChars = true;
            }
            if(!hasInvalidChars)
                finalString += line + Environment.NewLine;
        }

 //now store results
 using (System.IO.StreamWriter file = 
        new System.IO.StreamWriter(@"results.txt"))
 {
    file.write(finalString);
 }
```

then break the line into pieces:

Comment: Not sure why you are making the OP's homework for them.

Comment: I've been on his boat : )

Comment: So you just make it for them so they don't learn anything at all and just copy-paste your answer? Excellent way of **not** learning...

Comment: I have the weird ability of learning from codes that work and do something I know and understand. Anyhow this is not the place to discuss that.

Comment: @javirs, thanks for the code. I will try it and let you know. Thanks for the assistance and sorry that I did not post an example of the code that I have tried. I have tried too many things to remember.

Comment: BTW, I am not a developer by trade. This is some simple solution that the company was looking for and thought it would be an interesting challange to try and do it in C#. Turned out to be not as simple as I thought. I really appreciate the assistence. Thanks

Comment: @StevenBailey if it worked and does what you expected it to do you should accept the answer. This helps keeping stackexchange tidy

Comment: I was not able to produce the results using the code above. I have altered the code and tried many varients of the snipit above to no avail. I keep getting an error saying it cannot convert char to string. I am currently trying a few other things, once I have a solution I will post the working code here. Sorry for taking so long to respond and thanks for the assistance so far.

Comment: if you tell us what particular line is producing the error and the exact error we can further help you

Answer (score -2):

include reference =>using System.IO;
give you file Path where you have place your file and then call stream writer to write that file as i have write "i am good"
using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(FilePath))
                        {
                                `sw.Write("i am good");`
                        }

Comment: pls add some explanation about your solution

Comment: he wants to REMOVE lines in the text file, not create/write lines to it